# Why am I getting these assembler errors?

Tags: c++, gcc, inline-assembly

I have a big function that needs to convert from floats to integers at a point. Without this conversion the function takes 11-12 ns/loop on my machine. With the conversion it takes ~ 400 ns/loop.

After some reading I found a way to speed the conversion up using a bit of inline assembly. The first iteration of my function was as follows:

```
inline int FISTToInt (float f)
{
    int i;
    asm("fld %1;"
        "fistp %0;"
        :"=r" ( i )
        :"r" ( f )
        :
    );
    return i;
}
```

when I compiled that I got the following errors:

```
src/calcRunner.cpp: Assembler messages:
src/calcRunner.cpp:43: Error: operand type mismatch for `fld'
src/calcRunner.cpp:43: Error: operand type mismatch for `fistp'
```

A bit of thought supplied the answer, I forgot the instruction suffixes, so I changed the function to be as follows:

```
inline int FISTToInt (float f)
{
    int i;
    asm("flds %1;"
        "fistps %0;"
        :"=r" ( i )
        :"r" ( f )
        :
    );
    return i;
}
```

However this did not fix the problem, instead I get this:

```
src/calcRunner.cpp: Assembler messages:
src/calcRunner.cpp:43: Error: invalid instruction suffix for `fld'
src/calcRunner.cpp:43: Error: invalid instruction suffix for `fistp'
```

What is going on?

Comment: It's portable across x86 architectures, and in this case, I need the speed far more than I need the portability, especially given that the grid it will be running on is composed of x86 machines. This loop is run hundreds of trillions of times and I can only get 600 cores with the rules of my universities grid, therefor the loop needs to be very fast, thus assembly. If you are running on a limited set of architectures portability does not matter.

Comment: I think I know what the problem is (I'm also far from convinced that it will speed up much!). You need to use memory loads/stores when using fpu, not registers. I will test and write up an answer.

Comment: If you are going to bother writing assembly for speed you should consider SIMD instructions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions

Comment: And I use SIMD instructions in the form of __m128 res; _mm_load_ps(resids);_mm_mul_ps(res, res); etc. However, every cycle I have to convert a single float into an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
int trunk(float x)
{
    int i;
    __asm__ __volatile__(
    "    flds   %1\n"
    "    fistpl %0\n"
    : "=m"(i) : "m"(x));
    return i; 
}
```

However, it's only (possibly) faster than the compiler generated code if you are actually using x87 mode, and it's faster because it's not loading and storing the FP control word that determines the rounding. I will get back with a couple of benchmarks...

Simple benchmark:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int trunk(float x)
{
    int i;
    __asm__ __volatile__(
    "    flds   %1\n"
    "    fistpl %0\n"
    : "=m"(i) : "m"(x));
    return i; 
}


int trunk2(float x)
{
    return (int)x;
}

inline long long rdtsc()
{
    unsigned long a, d;
    __asm volatile ("rdtsc" : "=a" (a), "=d" (d) : : "ebx", "ecx"); 
    return a | ((long long)d << 32);
}


int main()
{
    float f[1000];
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
    f[i] = rand() / (i+1); 
    }
    long long t = rdtsc();
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
    sum = trunk(f[i]);
    }
    t = rdtsc() - t;
    printf("Sum=%d time=%ld\n", sum, t);

    t = rdtsc();
    sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
    sum = trunk2(f[i]);
    }
    t = rdtsc() - t;
    printf("Sum=%d time=%ld\n", sum, t);

    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with gcc -O2 -m64 -std=c99, it produces the following result:

```
Sum=1143565 time=30196
Sum=1143565 time=15946
```

In a 32-bit compile (gcc -O2 -m32 -std=c99):

```
Sum=1143565 time=29847
Sum=1143565 time=107618
```

In other words, it's a lot slower. However, if we enable sse2 (and remove: `gcc -m32 -msse2 -mfpmath=sse -O2`, it gets much better:

```
Sum=1143565 time=30277
Sum=1143565 time=11789
```

Note that the first number is "your solution", where the second result is the compiler's solution.

Obviously, please do measure on your system, to ensure the results do indeed match up.

Edit: After finding that I should actually add the numbers in the loop, rather than just walk through them putting them in `sum`, I get the following results for clang:

`clang -m32 -msse2 -mfpmath=sse -O2 floatbm.c -std=c99`

```
Sum=625049287 time=30290
Sum=625049287 time=3663
```

The explanation to why it is so much better in "let the compiler do the job" is that Clang 3.5 is producing an unrolled loop with proper SSE simd for the second loop - it can't do that for the first loop, so each iteration is 1 float value.

Just to show that gcc still gives the same result, I rerun with gcc:

```
Sum=625049287 time=31612
Sum=625049287 time=15007
```

Only difference from before is that I use `sum += trunk(f[i]);` instead of `sum = ...`.

Comment: For timing, I had been going off of this: http://stereopsis.com/sree/fpu2006.html. He demonstrated that "my solution" should be faster.

Comment: And you have tested it? Since 2006, there has been the odd little bit of development in for example compilers, and OS's today do support SSE2 and SSE3 instructions, which allow the compiler to "do a better job". If your compiler is a 64-bit x86 compiler, the result of your "optimisation" will be as my first results posted. In other words, about 2x slower than the compiler generated code. If you are compiling for x86 32 bit without sse, the middle result applies, and if you compile for 32-bit with sse2, you should get the same 2x worse.

Comment: Well even with gcc -O3 (version 4.5.1), the compiler generates code that takes a very long time comparitively speaking. I freely grant that things might have gotten better since then though. I used sse2 elsewhere in the loop, and it did well, that is what took things down to 11-12ns. When I used sse to, just before a final store and then add, convert to ints and simply add the ints, the loop still takes 200ns. I was looking for other ways. Of course I was going to benchmark this as I had everything else. But I was having trouble figuring out what was wrong in the first place.

Comment: I'm using a rather old gcc 4.6.3 (which is a little less buggy than 4.5, which according to my colleague is about the worst ever gcc version for bugs...)

Comment: For laughs, I also compiled with `clang`, but I think they "cheat", as the number that comes out is 224 clock cycles for the second loop - which says that they probably figured out that both loops do the same thing, and it's no point in doing the second loop. Shall see if I can make it not do that.

Comment: Fair enough, I was going to compile it under 4.8 once I got things working, in preparation for deployment to the grid. Thanks for answering my question.

Comment: I think clang is broken for this particular code - it doesn't at all do what I expect - even the LLVM IR output looks wrong. May have to file a bug... ;)

Comment: Alternatively, I could fix my code so that `sum` actually sums up the numbers within the loop, rather than just reading each one and keeping the last one... ;) - See edit above for clang results.

Answer (score 2):

Floats are memory operands, not register.  So you need this:

```
inline int FISTToInt (float f) {
    int i;
    asm("flds %1;"
        "fistl %0;"
        :"=m" ( i )
        :"m" ( f )
        :
    );
    return i;   
}
```

Note that `s` is for 16-bit integers, but 32-bit single (float) for floating point, and `l` is a 32-bit int for integers, but 64-bit double for floating point.

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/prwT2N)

[This seems like a decent resource](http://stereopsis.com/FPU.html)

Answer (score -1):

If you can do it faster than your compiler, throw that one as far as you possibly can, and get a decent one.

And please tell us here, so nobody else will even think of using it in earnest.

Comment: Well using the stuff available in xmmintrin.h I can crush the heck out of gcc -O3 (version 4.5.1), by a factor of 30 or so, in terms of speeding up the inner loop. However, I do not see anybody rushing to leave gcc anytime soon.